# Receiving UDP on different Android phones gives different results

Tags: android, udp, android-wifi, galaxy

I am willing to create a server and client program on my android mobile devices.
The devices communicate with each other on the same wifi network, therefore, some simple scanning mechanism must be implemented - The client phones search for a server phone through some kind of broadcast.

What I did:

My protocol - the client phone broadcasts a message port **p** on the wifi, the server listens on port **p**. when the server gets the broadcast message it sends a message back, therefore discovering itself to the client.

My code -
I have opened a broadcast socket on my app, it sends a broadcast message.
Meanwhile there is a python script on my PC that listens and replies - I use python so that my testing will be easier - Wireshark on the PC and I can see **everything**.

What happens:

When I use one of my Galaxy S phones - it works and I get a response.
When I use the other Galaxy S phone - it doesn't work.

Now this is what I know:
The phone that works actually has Nexus ROM on it Ver. 4.1.1
The phone that doesn't work has 2.3.3 regular galaxy ROM

The python code says it receives **both** of the broadcasts sent from **both** phones, and replies to both of them without raising any exception.

So far I was thought the problem may be
1. the older version'd phone.
2. the windows firewall
3. the router firewall

So I have opened Wireshark, and Indeed I saw that both phones are sending their broadcasts - it was logged on Wireshark.
**But the python script only responded to the first one.**
So this is why 1 & 3 are irrelevant - if the router firewall was blocking my UDP I would have still seen the python server response, same with the older versioned phone.

To get rid of 2 i just disabled the windows firewall - still same problem.

Does anyone has a clue to why this effect might happen?

Thanks!

Edit

My python code:

```
def scan(data, addr, sock):
    print "received scan message:", data, addr
    name = u"name".encode("utf-16-le")
    data = "DISC" + short2bytes(len(name)) + name
    print "sending back %s to %s" % (data, addr)
    sock.sendto(data, addr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(('', UDP_PORT))
    while 1:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1500)
        print "received packet " + data
        if data.startswith("SCAN"):
            scan(data, addr, sock)
```

edit 2:

Okay! Seems like my code and protocol DID work.
As it turns out the 2.3.3 phone had some severe ARP problems.
After some resets it works flawlessly!

Comment: You say this - "The python code says it receives both of the broadcasts sent from both phones, and replies to both of them without raising any exception.",  then you say this - " But the python script only responded to the first one".  Which one is true?

Comment: The python code indeed responds to both broadcasts - the code doesn't raise any exception. But Wireshark says that a response was sent only to the phone holding ver 4.1.1